# Python 3.11 TensorFlow install not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I've been spending the past few hours trying to install TensorFlow and have been running into a lot of problems.

I've looked at lots of other answered TensorFlow install questions on here and none of them have a solution for me.

Here is the error code I keep getting:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python311\Scripts\tensorboard.exe' -> 'C:\Python311\Scripts\tensorboard.exe.deleteme'`

I have triple checked the software requirements on the TensorFlow website so I know that that is not the issue.

I saw lots of people talking about how it only works with Python 64 bit so I already checked and I'm good there.

I tried watching YouTube videos on different ways to install it, making sure python.exe is a path variable and nothing is working.

I also have tried this line `pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl` since I've seen it in a lot of solutions and it didn't work.

Comment: Check this blog, it will resolve your issue. 

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-system-cannot-find-file-specified